# testing performance classifier matlab

Tags: matlab, testing, machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

Hello I have trained a classifier in matlab and I would like to test its accuracy.
I have found a lot of functions to do that and I am puzzling on what to use...

at the moment:

```
% train my classifier
svmStruct = fitcsvm(Xtrain,Ytrain,'KernelFunction','linear','Standardize',true);

% predict the output of an unknown input <- this part takes a lot of time
IDX_svm = zeros(size(Xtest,1),1);
for j = 1 : size(Xtest,1)    
    IDX_svm(j) = predict(svmStruct,Xtest(j,:));    
end

%compute performaces
TABLE = confusionmat(Ytest,IDX_svm);
sum_diag = 0;
for j = 1 : size(TABLE,2)
    sum_diag = sum_diag + TABLE(j,j);
end
error_rate = 1-(sum_diag/sum(sum(TABLE,2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy is simply defined as the ratio between the correctly predicted labels and the total number of labels in the testing/validation set. So instead of using the confusion matrix, if you have the Testing Labels vector (`Ytest` I suppose) and the Predicted Labels vector (`IDX_svm` I suppose), you can simply run

```
Accuracy=sum(IDX_svm==Ytest)/length(Ytest)
```

`Accuracy` will be in range [0;1], which you can scale in percentage by simply multiplying it by 100.

The Error Rate, of course, is defined according to one of the following:

- If you have previously evaluated the accuracy

  - `1-Accuracy` if `Accuracy` is in range [0;1]
  - `100-Accuracy` if `Accuracy` is given in percentage
- If you want to evaluate just the error rate

  - the ratio between the *in*correctly predicted labels and the total number of labels in the testing/validation set: `ErrorRate=sum(IDX_svm~=Ytest)/length(Ytest)`. Such value will be in range [0;1]
  - multiplying the above result by 100 will give the error rate in percentage

These are standard definitions and they work for every classifier, not just the SVM.

Also, I recommend to avoid the `predict()` function in a loop. In this case you call `predict()` several times and each call classifies a single point. This slows down your code. As you might now, `predict()` can take the whole testing matrix as input and returns the entire label vector so you don't have to preallocate and write every single element of such vector inside a for-loop. And you call `predict()` only once. You might want to try something like

```
IDX_svm=predict(svmStruct,Xtest);
```